# What was the Chinese Communist Party's organizational hierarchy in the two weeks between 15JUL1927 and 01Aug1927?

Tags: china, communism

According to Zhang Guotao, Nanchang Upgrising (01Aug1927) was Li Lisan's initiative inaugurated and proposed by Zhou Enlai to Zhang GuoTao. The decision to go ahead was made between Zhou Enlai and Zhang Guotao in the name of the Standing committee of CPC (中常委). Zhang admitted that this was the first important decision made in the absence of Moscow's endorsement.

Two months later when Zhou and Zhang were still in the jungle, both men were demoted by CPC Central Committee headed by Qu Qiubai in Shanghai.

I wander what the CPC's organizational hierarchy was like during this period. Who was supposed to take orders from who?

Source: Zhang, Guotao. The Rise of the Chinese Communist Party. Book 12, Chapter 6 "The Split." Eastern Publishing. 2004

Any insights from an anthropologist's point of view is appreciated.

Comment: What does "anthropology" (human culture) have to do with this question?

Comment: It seems that these revolutionists' habits of mind still belonged to the age they ended. Their attitudes towards authority remained unchanged. The only difference was that Moscow took the place of Beijing.

Comment: What leads you to believe that there is an answer to this question? Is it possible they were engaged in the process of thinking this out?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - What leads you to believe that there isn't an answer to this question? Is it possible they were not engaged in the process of thinking this out?

Comment: @GeorgeChen: The Communist Party of China was a mess by July, 1927. Maybe half of them were dead, and the other half were in hiding or running for their lives. Including Mao.

Comment: @TomAu - Exactly in crises like this, the governing dynamics shows its tail.

Comment: I'm trying to find out the habits of mind that gave rise to dictators after the fall of empires.